# Netbeans «Невозможно разрешить идентификатор»

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, gcc

Netbeans 8.0.2 (а также 8.1) постоянно «ругается» на вроде бы «здоровый» синтаксис выражением «Невозможно разрешить идентификатор». Как это пофиксить?

Компилируется код без ошибок (ниже приведен пример, а не реальный код). Файл создается непосредственно в IDE в кодировке UTF-8. Code Assistance (помощник по работе с кодом) включен. Повторный анализ проекта (Reparse project) не помогает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
} S;
std::map<int, S> m;
std::vector<int> v;

int main()
{
    for(auto &x : m)
        x.second.a = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: похоже, известная бага. И даже предлагается как ее пофиксить - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242729 и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733969/configure-c11-properly-on-netbeans-8-0-2-on-mac

Comment: @KoVadim т.е. я правильно понимаю, что это известный баг, который никто и не собирается фиксить? Несколько лет ему, сменились несколько версий/подверсий, а он до сих пор существует? Ну да ладно, а как все-таки его пофиксить? Я же не собираю netbeans из исходников.

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что у вас правильно настроены компиляторы в NetBeans - во-первых, убедитесь что они есть, во-вторых, стоит C++11 стандарт, раз вы им пользуетесь.

1. Tools -> Options -> C/C++. На первой вкладке (Build Tools) можно добавить или отредактировать существующий tool collection (то есть компиляторы)
2. Project Properties -> Build. Здесь укажите добавленный/настроенный tool collection
3. Project Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> C++ Standard. Здесь укажите C++11